# Solve the homogeneous differential equation $y^2+x^2y'=xyy'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y^2 + x^2y'=xyy'$

Here's what I did:

$y^2=(xy-x^2)y'$

$\frac{y^2}{xy-x^2}=y'$

$\frac{\frac{y^2}{x^2}}{\frac{y}{x}-1}$=y'

$v=\frac yx$

$\frac{v^2}{v-1}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$

$\frac{v}{v-1}=x\frac{dv}{dx}$

$\frac{dx}x=1-\frac1vdv$

$\int1-\frac1vdv=\int\frac1xdx$

$v-ln|v|=ln|x|+C$

$\frac yx -ln|\frac yx|=ln|x|+C$

Apparently, the correct answer is

$\frac1{\sqrt{y(y-2x)}}=C$

Can someone help me find what I did wrong?

Comment: This looks right to me. I don't see a mistake at all.

Comment: After consulting Wolfram Alpha, your steps are correct. Are you sure you didn't mistake the answer for a different question or attempt the wrong problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the supposed correct answer $$\frac1{\sqrt{y(y-2x)}}=c$$ We can solve for $y$ as a function of $x$ and get $$y_{\pm}=x\pm\frac{\sqrt{c^4 x^2+c^2}}{c^2}$$ None of them satisfy $y^2+x^2y'=xyy'$. So, more than likely, there is a typo in the problem.

On the other side, your work is very good. You could be interested by the fact that using your last expression $$\frac yx -\log|\frac yx|=\log|x|+c$$ you are very close to an explicit solution in which Lambert function appears $$y=-x W\left(-\frac{e^{-c}}{x}\right)$$